# How to implement the template view pattern with a table?

Tags: php, design-patterns

At the moment I'm trying to understand the template view pattern using PHP.

I got a table that gets filled by a command (using command pattern). At the moment the array gets iterated and filled in a table using foreach. I want to split the program logic and the displaying of the table but I don't know where to declare the table and how to fill it.

I understood it generally. I'm able to display a single information. 
Two questions:

- How to implement it when I want to display a table from a database?
- How to implement the content that should be displayed on all pages?

Unfortunately everything I found is about template engines that I don't want to use at the moment.

Here is the command combined with a table generator. I want to split that into a command that retrieves the data and a view that displays the table.

```
    $domains = ConcreteDomainFactory::getAllDomains();
    echo '<table class="domain-table">';
        echo '<thead>';
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<th>ID</th>';
                echo '<th>Domain</th>';
                echo '<th>Beschreibung</th>';
                echo '<th>aktiviert</th>';
            echo '</tr>';
        echo '</thead>';
        echo '<tbody>';

    if((is_array($domains) ===true) && (count($domains) > 0)){
        $line_number = 1;

        foreach($domains as $domain){
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . $domain->getPkDomainId() . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $domain->getDomain() . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $domain->getDescription() . '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                    if($domain->getActive()){
                        echo 'ja';
                    }
                    else{
                        echo 'nein';
                    }
                echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
        echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';`
```

Comment: you can easily make a html table generator. try it out yourself and comeback with your code if you have "the" actual problem

Comment: added the actual code